# upgrading to Gradle 5.2.1 does not generate a *-all.jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, shadowjar

I recently upgraded my java project to gradle 5.2.1, from gradle version 2.0.  In gradle 2.0, doing a `./gradlew shadowJar` created a file called: `hthu-email-service-3.0.0-all.jar`.. this file would ALWAYS be generated.

After upgrading to 5.2.1, doing a `./gradlew shadowJar`, NO LONGER produces this `hthu-email-service-3.0.0-all.jar` file. The missing file is thus causing major issues.

Any thoughts on how I can get `./gradlew shadowJar` to produce this `hthu-email-service-3.0.0-all.jar` file again with gradle 5.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

must upgrade to 5.0 for this package: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.0.0